# When to use React useCallback hook

Tags: reactjs, usecallback

In my below React component I am fetching more items using [Apollo Client `fetchMore` function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api/).

What is exactly the purpose of using [React useCallback hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) here? And is it good idea to use that in this case?

```
const Carousel = ({ data: blockData, metadata }: Props) => {

  const { data, fetchMore, networkStatus } = useQuery<
   GqlRes,
  >(GET_NODES, {
    variables: {
      offset
      limit
    },
    errorPolicy: 'all',
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    ssr: false,
  });


  const fetchNextPage = useCallback(() => {
    return fetchMore({
      variables: {
        offset: data?.getNodes.nodes.length,
      },
    });
  }, [data, fetchMore]);

  const items =
    data?.getNodes.nodes
      .map((node) => {
        return {
          id: node.id,
          title: node.title,
        };
      }) || [];

  return (
    <Carousel
      items={items}
        onEnd={() => {
         if (data?.getNodes.pager?.hasNextPage) {
           fetchNextPage();
         }
      }}
    />
  )
};

export default Carousel;
```

Comment: The useCallback hook is used when you have a component in which the child is rerendering again and again without need. Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed.

Comment: There is no point in using `useCallback` here because you are passing a new function to `Carousel` on every render anyways. `useCallback` is useful if you are passing a function to a child component and you only want to pass a new function object when any of the data that the function uses changes. This allows the child component to do optimizations.

Comment: @Felix Kling and inside `Carousel` there is another `<Child />` where `onEnd` is passed through. Does that make any difference? Ans sorry can you give a clear use case when to use it?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO:

1. if your inner 'Carousel' component is cached (memoized by `React.memo` or extends `PureComponent`) it's could to do not provide new properties on each parent (outer 'Carousel') re-render (just to mention - on each re-render you not memoized objects and function will be created again as new instances and will be passed further as new properties and cause new re-renders of children) it's to use `useCallback`
2. even more, I would like to use `useMemo` for your '*items*' data variable to avoid that logic re-handling. Yes for it's logically will be new on each update of '*data*' or other properties from a parent, BUT when someone will extend the logic of the component and it will be re-rendered, then data handling could be not changed and that logic will be redundant - you safe time of component logic handling